# Filter FullCalendar events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar plugin to display events from my database. I store events in instance variable and display them in View. User can choose an option from drop down menu and depending to that option, events will be filtered. The problem is that I can't do that filtering. I'm trying a couple of days already.

This is my root 'home' View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
  setCalendar(<%= @doctors.first.id %>);

  $("#doctor_id").change(function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    setCalendar(selectedVal);
  });

  function setCalendar(doctor_id){

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/appointments",
      data: "doctor_id=" + doctor_id,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
          alert(data[0].id);          
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    })

  // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    disableResizing: true,
    disableDragging: true,

        events: 
        [
        <% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
        {
          id     : "<%= appointment.id %>",
          title  : "Reserved",
          start  : "<%= appointment.start_date.in_time_zone.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
          end    : "<%= appointment.end_date.in_time_zone.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
          allDay : false
        },
        <% end %>
        ],



 ...
```

Controller:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def home

    if params[:doctor_id]
      @appointments = Appointment.where(doctor_id: params[:doctor_id])
    else
      @appointments = Appointment.all
    end

    @doctors = Doctor.all
  end

end
```

My routes:

```
root  'static#home'
match '/appointments',  to: 'static#home', via: 'get'
```

The problem is that filter doesn't work. Instance variable '@appointments' always contains all events and all events are displayed on calendar. Any ideas what is wrong inside this code?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54882281/how-to-customize-the-data-of-fullcalenderbundle-symfony4?noredirect=1#comment96595946_54882281

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi there Zdravko Vajudin this is actually very simple to do, let me explain how do i do it using a checkbox (with dropdown you can figure it out for sure): ( Working code for version of **Fullcalendar** **1.6.4** )

STEP 1 - SOURCES DEFINITION BEFORE CALENDAR CALL

```
var sources = {         
                         sourceone: {               
                                        url: yourURL1,
                                        type: 'POST', 
                                        data:{
                                            'year':y                                        
                                        },
                                        cache: false,              
                                        color: '#C1272D',
                                        textColor: 'white'                             
                                     },                                  
                           sourcetwo: {                
                                        url: yourURL2,
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        data:{      
                                            'year':y
                                        },
                                        cache: false,              
                                        color: '#FF931E',
                                        textColor: 'white'       
                            }   
};
```

STEP 2 - CALENDAR INITIALIZATION

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
...
eventSources: [sources.sourceone,sources.sourcetwo] //You can define calling a function here that return's this array of sources, your choice
...
});
```

STEP 3 - FUNCTION TO REMOVE SOURCE FROM CALENDAR AND ADD IF CHECKED OR NOT

```
function filterEvents(var here if you want){        
        if(_CHECKBOX_FILTER.checked){ //_CHECKBOX_FILTER = document.getElementById("mycheckbox");           
            calendar.fullCalendar('removeEventSource', source.sourceone);
        }else{      
            calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', source.sourceone);
        }
```

STEP 4 - HTML :P

```
Remove Source one: <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="1" onclick="filterEvents()"/>
```

STEP 5 - FIGURE IT OUT HOW TO DO IT WITH A DROPDOWN

```
//TODO Go work :P and dont forget to give +1 if it helped ;)
```