# How to customize the Data of FullCalenderBundle [Symfony4]

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig, fullcalendar

I have added a select form above the calendar to select an user and show his events(entity booking for example)on the Fullcalendar

so my question is, how the data of FullCalenderBundle change by the user selected in the form?

this is some of files,

FullCalenderListener.php

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use App\Entity\Booking;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Toiba\FullCalendarBundle\Entity\Event;
use Toiba\FullCalendarBundle\Event\CalendarEvent;

class FullCalendarListener
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @var UrlGeneratorInterface
     */
    private $router;

    private $security;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, UrlGeneratorInterface $router,Security $security)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendar)
    {
        $startDate = $calendar->getStart();
        $endDate = $calendar->getEnd();
        $filters = $calendar->getFilters();

        // Modify the query to fit to your entity and needs
        // Change b.beginAt by your start date in your custom entity
        $user = $this->security->getUser();

        $bookings = $this->em->getRepository(Booking::class)
            ->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->where('b.Responsable = :responsable')
            ->setParameter('responsable', $user->getUsername())
            ->andWhere('b.beginAt BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
            ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->getQuery()->getResult();

        foreach($bookings as $booking) {

            // this create the events with your own entity (here booking entity) to populate calendar
            $bookingEvent = new Event(
                $booking->getTitle(),
                $booking->getBeginAt(),
                $booking->getEndAt() // If the end date is null or not defined, it creates a all day event
            );

            /*
             * Optional calendar event settings
             *
             * For more information see : Toiba\FullCalendarBundle\Entity\Event
             * and : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object
             */
            // $bookingEvent->setUrl('http://www.google.com');
            // $bookingEvent->setBackgroundColor($booking->getColor());
            // $bookingEvent->setCustomField('borderColor', $booking->getColor());

            $bookingEvent->setUrl(
                $this->router->generate('booking_show', array(
                    'id' => $booking->getId(),
                ))
            );

            // finally, add the booking to the CalendarEvent for displaying on the calendar
            $calendar->addEvent($bookingEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

calendar.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}


{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white">Choose a user</div>
        <div class="p-3 mb-2">{{ form(form) }}</div>
        <div class="bg-light">
            <a href="{{ path('booking_new') }}">Create new booking</a>
            {% include '@FullCalendar/Calendar/calendar.html.twig' %}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar/locale-all.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({
                height: 'parent',
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
                locale: 'fr',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev, next, today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
                },
                businessHours: {
                    start: '09:00',
                    end: '18:00',
                    dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                },
                height: "auto",
                contentHeight: "auto",
                lazyFetching: true,
                navLinks: true,
                selectable: true,
                editable: true,
                eventDurationEditable: true,
                eventSources: [
                    {
                        url: "{{ path('fullcalendar_load_events') }}",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data:  {
                            filters: {}
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('There was an error while fetching FullCalendar!');
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried so much and i can't do it, thank you for your help

Comment: you'd have to submit the form data to the server (via postback or ajax), save it into the database and then run "refetchEvents" in fullCalendar to get it to re-load the events from the server (unless of course, you used a postback in which case just refreshing the page will do that job already)

Comment: Thank you for your reponse, but i haven't understood so much, Can you code it to me?

I have another question, Can i get the request form, from the listener FullCalenderListener.php and change sql request depending on data of form ?

Comment: yes you can vary your SQL query based on some data input in the request. The same is true of any request you make to the server.

Comment: As for the rest, specifically what part of the process I described are you not understanding?

Comment: @Khalil do you want do a something like filter by user or something like each connected user see only there own events ?

Comment: @ThéoAttali I mean filter by user

Comment: @Khalil do you want a direct link to the calendar user?

Comment: no, in same calendar (page)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a select of your users and do something like this

```
$('#users').on('change', function() {
    var userId = this.value;

    $('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({ 
        eventSources: [{
            url: "{{ path('fullcalendar_load_events') }}",
            type: 'POST',
            data:  {
                filters: {
                    user_id: userId,
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('There was an error while fetching FullCalendar!');
            }
        }]
    });
    $('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
});
```

in your listener you can now update the query accordingly

```
$bookings = $this->em->getRepository(Booking::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('booking')
    ->where('booking.beginAt BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
    ->innerJoin('booking.user', 'user')
    ->andWhere('user.id = :userId')
    ->setParameter('userId', $filters['user_id'])
    ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```